# Why is this wrong? Calculate 3D position from acceleration

Tags: integration, convergence-acceleration

I would like to ask a question related to math/physics since I'm just a developer and I don't have enough physics knowledge to solve this problem alone.
I'm trying to calculate a 3d position having the acceleration.
Before explaining any further, I try to give you a more context.
Actually I'm trying to build a sort of "Playstation Move" using an accelerometer + gyroscope sensor for a Unity Project.
Without explaining in depth, imagine that I've this sensor that, applying a force, gives me those value.
In Unity (software to develop videogames), I've a 3d object placed (imagine a cube) in a 3d World (so I know its starting position).
Some people said that, to calculate the position, I need to Integrate twice the acceleration and I understand.
But, according to acceleration formula (If i understood properly): 
Having $m = meters$ and $s = seconds$

### $a= m/s^{2}$

So, using the inverse, I can easily do something like this:

### $a \cdot s^{2} = m$

From my point of view, this seems a correct calculation and I don't need to integrate anything. 
Can I ask you why my idea is wrong and why I need to Integrate twice instead?
I hope I explained well what's my doubt.
PS: I know that could be a stupid question, but I can't find anything related.

Comment: What is $m$, and what is $s$? Where did you get "the acceleration formula" you wrote, i.e. the formula $a=\frac{m}{s^2}$?

Comment: I mean, m are meter and s are seconds. Maybe this is wrong but I read something about that on Internet

Comment: If $m$ are meters and $s$ are seconds, then $m/s^2$ is not the acceleration, it is just the **unit** of acceleration. A unit for something is not the same as that something. Me saying "My height is $m$" is a nonsensical sentence. The sentence only makes sense if I add a value, i.e. "My height is $1.71m$". See my answer below for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula for the acceleration is $$a=\frac{d^2x}{dt^2},$$ where the value $x$ describes the position of a particle at a given time. From this definition, it should be clear that given $a$ (the acceleration), you can calculate $x$ (the position) by integrating $a$ twice (because, roughly speaking, integration is a reverse operation to derivation).

---

I do not know where you got the formula $a=\frac{m}{s^2}$. That expression itself does not make much sense, since $m$ and $s$ are not defined.

Note: If by $m$ you mean meters, and $s$ stands for seconds, then $\frac{m}{s^2}$ is not equal to acceleration, but is only the **unit** of acceleration. In that case, the equation $a=\frac{m}{s^2}$ is incorrect, and in fact nonsensical, because the **left** side of the equation holds a value, while the **right** side of the equation does not (it only has a unit).

Comment: Good answer. The first paragraph lacks integration constants, which makes it incomplete (close to false). One _can_ calculate the position by double integration _if_ one knows and includes the constants for both integrals – the starting position and the initial velocity of the particle.

Comment: You're completely right, that's his notation, not the formula.
Related to the acceleration formula I've no doubt.
But I still have the previous doubt.
I try to make my question easier (so you can find better where is my mistake).
I've a car that run at 60 kilometer per hour -> $velocity = 60km/h$.
If I would like to know how many kilometers that car traveled after 2 hours I can simply say $120km$ cause I multiplied the hours with the velocity to obtain the kilometers.
Now, if I've the acceleration and the seconds, why I can't do the same to find the meters?

Comment: I guess I got it.
Actually my example is wrong because I defined on my own "after two hours". With my example I can "predict" the kilometers. I'm not figuring out everything yet (because I don't have enough knowledge yet) but I guess I'm starting to understand your comment

Comment: @Eloh If the velocity is constant, then the equation is $v=\frac{s}{t}$, where $s$ is the distance travelled and $t$ is the time taken. And you can, from **that** equation, calculate that $s=v\cdot t$, i.e. that the distance is the velocity times the acceleration. But note that I multiplied the equation with the **TIME**, not with the **unit** of time, i.e. with the hours.

Comment: @Eloh You cannot just "multiply with hours" ,that makes zero sense. You can multiply the equation with **time**, but time is not "hours", it is "the number of hours". That's not the same thing. You got $120km$ not because you multiplied the hours with the velocity, but because you multiplied the **TIME** with the velocity.

Comment: @Eloh Also note that in general, the distance travelled is calculated as the integral of the velocity over time. The equation $s=v\cdot t$ holds **only** if the velocity is constant, because in that case, $$\int_{0}^t v d\tau = v\cdot t.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've all the information I needed. I had some problem because I'm studying physics on my own and it's not that simple at the beginning. But know is much clear. Thanks a lot again @5xum , you really helped me

Comment: @Eloh If my answer is what you needed, don't forget to accept it so it doesn't show up on the "unanswered" lists...